# Blending the intersections of separate objects in a rigged character for a metaball-esque/remeshing effect?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

Is there a way to achieve this in Blender? I'm looking for an approach to **blend the intersections** between **separate objects** that comprise the different parts of a rigged character, to arrive at something that looks similar to joining and beveling the geometry, or joining and plugging a bevel node into a shader node's normal input, but **while keeping the objects separate and unjoined.** This would ideally work like a real time remeshing of these separate objects, so that areas would seem to fuse as they're animated to overlap, almost like metaballs. (Using metaballs won't work in this application because each part needs to retain a specifically sculpted geometry. I've simplified my example for the sake of streamlining.)

I've tried to illustrate the setup I'm envisioning here using color coding to designate the separate objects.

Here's an example that's doing something similar to what I'm going for, (though a bit more extreme). Nickelodeon blob bumper (1993): https://twitter.com/i/status/1144621399056633861
The dino and little walking guy come pretty close to the intended behavior.

[image]